# Setattr method is not being called when appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why when appending or concatenating an object attribute's list or dictionary `__setattr__` method is not being called. The methods description "Called when an attribute assignment is attempted." would lead me to believe that concatenating the two list would work but the `__setattr__` method is still not being called.

```
class objVal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.articles = {'testkeyword': [1,2,3], 'testkeyword1': [4,5,6]}
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(objVal, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        print('setattr: ' + str(key) + '=' + str(value))

test = objVal()

templist = [11,12,13]
keyword = 'testkeyword'

test.articles[keyword] = test.articles[keyword] + templist # Does not trigger setattr
for item in templist: 
    test.articles[keyword].append(item) # Does not trigger setattr

print(test.articles[keyword])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__setattr__()` is called when the following syntax is used:

```
obj.key = value
# obj.__setattr__('key', value)
```

Note that *invoking a method* (e.g. calling `.append()`) does not activate this, because you're not directly setting anything to it. (retrieving the `append` method  would trigger `__getattr__()` though).

In most cases, if you designed a class, you'd end up calling `__setattr__()` at some point down the line anyway - but for most built-in classes, the functionality is abstracted away, handled via macro, or something else that 'skips' the `__setattr__()` step.

---

Note that the `__setitem__()` method also exists on some objects (not all!), and is different from `__setattr__()` because it gets invoked by a different syntax:

```
obj[key] = value
# obj.__setitem__('key', value)
```

but, as far as I remember, calling `.append()` on a list will usually not trigger that either, though it may depend on which implementation of python you're running. This is for the reason outlined above - the interpreter uses shortcuts to get the job done for some of the core built-in classes.